# How to add elements to listview from parameter

Tags: java, android, list, arraylist

I'm trying to add the elements I pass to parameter, lets say I need to add 10 elements to my list, so I will need, 10 .add , so I want to do this to be able to load different spinners with the same method, this is what I have made too far

```
 private void setSpinnerData(Spinner spinner){
        List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
        spinnerArray.add("item1");
        spinnerArray.add("item2");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

What I need is something like this

```
 private void setSpinnerData(Spinner spinner,int elementsToAdd){
        List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i = 0 ; i<elementsToAdd;i++){
        spinnerArray.add(i);
       }


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

but I need to define each of those alements to be added, how I do that ?

Comment: what do u mean by I need to define each of those alements to be added

Comment: passing the parameter (Spinner spinner) I define wich spinner will be filled with the data that is added with .add , now , what I want is just to add data to the spinner programatically, lets say I need 5 elements to that spinner , I want to say , add 5, and then define those 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that's what you want :

```
private void setSpinnerData(Spinner spinner,String... params){
        List<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();

        for(String str:params){
            spinnerArray.add(str);
        }

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);

        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

or if you need to pass an ArrayList:

```
 private void setSpinnerData(Spinner spinner,ArrayList<String> dataList){

            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dataList);

            adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

            spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: so, do I need to make an array of Strings to pass there ?

Comment: setSpinnerData(spinner,"String1","String2","String3");

Comment: setSpinnerData(spinner,"String1");

Comment: if you need to pass array of strings let me now so I can edit my solution

Comment: for some reason is not loading the data

Comment: Yes, i need to pass an array of possible items

Comment: The second solution is working, but the first looks more clean, is there anyway to do it like the first way? thanks so much

Comment: I just updated the second code , maybe now the 2nd looks cleaner and better ? and if you need to use the first please tell me more what is happening